# Filtering an UL by multiple filters by parsing XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, html

Right now, I am working on my first real programming project, but right now, I ran into a problem.
I have an unordered list, with one list-item for each filter criteria. Looking like this:

```
<li data-xml-code="gefäße-vorhanden" class="FilterListElement">Gefäße Vorhanden</li>
<li data-xml-code="splintholz-farblich-abgesetzt" class="FilterListElement">Splintholz farblich vom Kernholz abgesetzt</li>
```

each of them containing an data-attribute called "data-xml-code" to make a refernce lateron possible. Another script is adding an additional class called "selected" to the list-elements which highlights them through CSS. There are about 60 different criterias to filter, so see this code as an example.

My xml structure looks like this:

```
<wood_data>
<wood id="fagus_sylvatica">
    <name lang="de">Rotbuche</name>
    <name lang="en">European beech</name>
    <scientific_name>Fagus sylvatica</scientific_name>

    <attributes>
        <attribute>gefäße-vorhanden</attribute>
        <attribute>splintholz-farblich-abgesetzt</attribute>
    </attributes>
</wood>

<wood id="some_tree">
 ...
</wood>

</wood_data>
```

And there is a second list, that is directly built out of the name tags from the xml file. It creates list entries based in the id-tag of the woods in the xml as you would expect. Looking like this in the end:

```
<li id="fagus_sylvatica" class="WoodListElement">European beech</li>
```

What I am asking you is how to build a function in jQuery, that does the following:

- check for all FilterListElements, that also have the class="selected" and get the "data-xml-code"-attribute from them
- parse the xml, and hide every element in the WoodList, that is missing at least one of the selected filter tags.

My problem was, that I could not find a way to compare these two different sets of values. Could you please show me, how it's done?

Final solution:
Thanks a lot Shilly, I took your code and learned a lot from it. After combining it with some input from other threads, I want to present the working final code here:

```
function advancedFilter (){
$(this).toggleClass("selected");

activeFilters = [];

$('li.selected[data-xml-code]').map(function() {
    activeFilters.push($(this).attr('data-xml-code'));
});



$.ajax({
    url: 'xml/wooddata.xml',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(data) {
        $(data).find('wood').each(function (){

            var currentID = $(this).attr("id");
            var attr = $(this).find('attributes');
            //count = 0;
            found = [];


            attr.children().map(function(){
                found.push($(this).text());
            });


            var diff = $(activeFilters).not(found).get();


            if(diff!=0){
                $('.WoodListElement[id="' + currentID + '"]').slideUp();
            }else{
                $('.WoodListElement[id="' + currentID + '"]').slideDown();
            };
        });
    }
});
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Get the `data-xml-code` selected elements. Something resembling (my jquery isn't 100%, so doublecheck if you copy/paste) :

```
var codes = $('li .FilterListElement .selected').map(function (el) {
    return el.getAttribute('data-xml-code');
});
```

2) Get the value from the xml. Use tag names and `nodevalue`.

```
var xmlAttributes = function xmlAttributes( xml ) {
    var attr = xml.getElementsByTagName('attributes')[0],
        count,
        found = [];
    for (count = 0; count < attr.childNodes.length; count += 1) {
        found.push(attr.childNodes[count].nodeValue);
    }
    return found;
};
```

3) You can parse each xml fragment with the function to get the list of attributes that xml has and compare it with the list of codes we extracted from the list elements, which is trivial. I'd advice saving the parsed attributes somewhere so you only have to parse the xml once. Personally, I usually cast my incoming xml to json ebfore saving it, so I have easier access to the values and only have to parse xml once for each record.